# Заполнение строки данными из несмежных диапазонов

Tags: массивы, excel, vba, типы-данных

Прошу подсказать, почему возникает ошибка при заполнении массива?

Несколько раз проверял синтаксис, вроде всё нормально, но не работает. Жму `F8` (пошаговое выполнение макроса), но попытка заполнить массив в строке `NumStrok = Array(...)` вызывает ошибку.

Что не так?

```
Sub Макрос1()
    Dim NumStrok(1 To 21) As String
    NumStrok = Array("B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7", "B8", "H11", "I11", "J11", "K11", "H13", "I13", "J13", "K13", "B14", "D14", "B15", "D15", "H16")
    Dim NumKol(1 To 21) As String
    NumKol = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U")
    Dim OrgData(21) As Variant
    Dim KakaStroka As String

    Sheets("Ввод").Select

    For i = 1 To 21
      OrgData(i) = Range(NumStrok)
    Next

    KakaStroka = CStr(CInt(OrgData(1)) + 4)

    Sheets("База").Select

    For i = 1 To 21
      Range(NumKol + KakaStroka) = OrgData(i)
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка не одна, их много. А без понимания конечной задачи код смотрится сборной солянкой.

1. Не нужно задавать размерность массива, если он будет заполняться диапазоном с листа или массивом констант. При объявлении массива размерность можно задать, если он впоследствии будет заполняться поэлементно.

`OrgData(i) = .Range(NumStrok)` Хотите передать в массив значение ячейки? Не тут-то было...

2. Во-первых, сразу же ошибка - не указан элемент массива-передатчика, надо  `NumStrok(i)`.
3. При декларации массива `OrgData` указано, что его элементы типа `Variant` (т.е. могут быть любого типа). В цикле массив заполняется `Range(NumStrok(i))`... Но чем? В  `OrgData` может быть передано значение, которое находится по ссылке, но может быть записан и адрес ссылки!

*Вывод*. Всегда явно указывать, что хотим получить - `Range(NumStrok(i)).Value`

4. Знак + (плюс). Это может быть и объединение текстовых строк, и суммирование числовых данных. И его действие зависит от первого элемента перед знаком.

`CInt(OrgData(1)) + 4` - здесь в элементе массива может быть текст `"B2"` (см. выше ошибку 3). Попытка задать тексту тип "целое" - ошибка. Если без `CInt`, получим конкатенацию (объединение строк) - `"B2" + 4 = "B24"`

`Range(NumKol + KakaStroka)` - здесь `NumKol` - число, предполагается суммирование, но `KakaStroka` - текcт. Результат попытки суммирования с текстом - ошибка. Если в `KakaStroka` число в текстовом формате (ведь переменная типа `String`), получим суммирование двух чисел - номера столбца и номера строки. Догадайтесь, что будет :)

*Вывод*. Для суммирования применять + , для объединения текстов &. Если в переменной предполагается хранение числового значения, то почему эта переменная декларируется строковой?

5. *Примечание*. Почему в примере выше `B2`, а не `B1`? Если в модуле не декларирован оператор принудительного указания первого элемента массивов, то при заполнении массивом констант по умолчанию первый элемент массива - 0 (ноль). Отсюда еще дна неточность - цикл нужно начинать с нуля, а не с единицы.
6. `Sheets("Ввод").Select`. Для обращения к диапазонам не обязательно активировать лист.
7. Массив  `NumKol` лишний. Ссылку можно формировать и так: `Cells(KakaStroka, i) = OrgData(i)`
8. Массив `OrgData` и первый цикл тоже лишние, если значение `.Range(NumStrok(i))` передавать во втором цикле напрямую в ячейки.

Но можно поступить по-другому. Обращение к объектам листа - процесс медленный. Лучше значения массива передать в диапазон, без цикла.

Если задумка понята правильно, код может быть таким:

```
Sub Макрос1()
    Dim NumStrok(), OrgData(20)
    Dim KakaStroka As Long ' перевод: совсем плохая строка :) '
    Dim j As Long

    NumStrok = Array("B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7", "B8", "H11", "I11", "J11", "K11", "H13", "I13", "J13", "K13", "B14", "D14", "B15", "D15", "H16")

    With Sheets("Ввод")
        For j = 0 To 20
            OrgData(j) = .Range(NumStrok(j)).Value
        Next j

        KakaStroka = OrgData(0) + 4
        Sheets("Ввод").Cells(KakaStroka, 1).Resize(1, 21).Value = OrgData
    End With
End Sub
```

*Дополнение*. Неважно, в каком месте кода декларируются переменные, память откусывается сразу, в начале работы макроса.